# Wrong arrangement of boxes in raster of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

The following MWE constructs raster boxes of `tcolorbox`.

There are two problems with these code:

1. Boxes do not rank on line, but in different rows.
2. The second row in `#2` box is not filled.

Please see the attached figure for details.

Anyone can help me with the above two problems? Thank you.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myset}[1]{
  \def\columns{#1}
}

\tcbset{a/.style={
    code={\myset{#1}},
    raster multicolumn=\columns,
  }}

\begin{tcbitemize}[title=\#\thetcbrasternum,raster columns=4,raster equal height=rows,raster width=\linewidth]
  \tcbitem 1
  \tcbitem[%
  code={\myset{3}},%
  raster multicolumn=\columns,
  ]
  \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=\columns]
    \tcbitem columns now is: \columns \tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1
    \tcbitem[a=2] columns now is: \columns \tcbitem 2 
  \tcbitem columns now is: \columns
  \end{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem 3
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\myset` command? Do you really need it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, `\myset` is really needed. As an example, it just difine a macro now. Later, more functions will be added to `\myset`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problem 1

You need to replace:

```latex
\newcommand{\myset}[1]{
  \def\columns{#1}
}
```

with:

```latex
\newcommand{\myset}[1]{%
  \def\columns{#1}%
}
```

The code in the argument of `/tcb/code` is not passed to `\pgfkeys`, it is used in the body of the LaTeX document. Spaces matter and apparently prevent `tcolorbox` from seeing the immediately-following `tcolorbox` here.

## Problem 2

In several places, you use code such as `raster columns=\columns` or `raster multicolumn=\columns`. This is dangerous, because you don't know whether the underlying code will store the control sequence token `\columns` or will (maybe) expand it and (hopefully) store the result of this expansion. This is what is causing your second problem. When `a=2` is run from `\tcbitem[a=2]`, this modifies the meaning of `\columns` which is stored *as is* by a previously-issued `raster columns=\columns`. I suggest to use the `pgfkeys` `.expand once` handler to expand the value of `\columns` *before* passing the result to `raster columns` or other `tcolorbox` keys, as in:

```latex
raster columns/.expand once=\columns
```

or

```latex
raster columns/.expand once={\columns}
```

## Working code

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, hmargin=3cm]{geometry} % example
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newcommand{\myset}[1]{%
  \def\columns{#1}%
}

\tcbset{a/.style={
    code={\myset{#1}},
    raster multicolumn/.expand once=\columns,
  }}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[title=\#\thetcbrasternum, raster columns=4,
                   raster equal height=rows, raster width=\linewidth]
  \tcbitem 1
  \tcbitem[code={\myset{3}}, raster multicolumn/.expand once=\columns]
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns/.expand once=\columns]
      \tcbitem columns now is: \columns \tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1
      \tcbitem[a=2] columns now is: \columns \tcbitem 2
      \tcbitem columns now is: \columns
    \end{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem 3
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## Note

Of course, in case `\columns` is not needed in further code, you can pass the value directly and avoid some occurrences of problem 2 in a more straightforward way:

```latex
\tcbset{a/.style={raster multicolumn={#1}, whatever else...}}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Your version perfectly solve my first problem. It seems that the second problem is still there after compiling your code.

Comment: I had overlooked the second problem. Please see the latest edit.

Comment: Note: someone retracted his upvote at about the same time as [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505543/wrong-arrangement-of-boxes-in-raster-of-tcolorbox/505546#comment1277181_505546) was posted. I had already analyzed and fixed problem 1, but apparently this didn't deserve any upvote. Very well, but please bear in mind that I abhor this attitude of dangling a carrot in front of the person who is helping for free. If this kind of behavior continues, I'll stop answering questions and/or leave the site.

Comment: This solution -- `.expand once` is so great! I really appreciate your help on my question!! And sorry for upvote so late.